# Find a referenced metaobject for each item in cart

Tags: shopify, liquid, metaobject

I am using metaobjects and refernce them in certain products.
In my cart liquid, I want to loop over the products and find all references to the metaobject. If one is linked to a product in the cart, I need to access additional data in the metaobject.

How can I access the metaobject data in liquid?
Or how do I use the generated GIDs?

I am currently finding the metaobject like this:
`{% for item in cart.items %} {% if item.product.metafields.custom.object_upsell %} {{ item.product.metafields.custom.object_upsell }} --> here, I get e.g. ["gid://shopify/Metaobject/9076982","gid://shopify/Metaobject/9044214"] {% endif %} {% endfor %}`

When I try and loop over the object like this, I get no output at all:
`{% assign referencedObjects = item.product.metafields.custom.upsell_to %} {% for object in referencedObjects %} {{ object }} {% endfor %}`

I expected to still get an output of the gids, here.

Comment: I think you just need .values at the end of the reference to the metaobject

{% for item in cart.items %} 
  {% if item.product.metafields.custom.object_upsell %} 
    {% assign referencedObjects = item.product.metafields.custom.object_upsell.values %}
    {% for object in referencedObjects %} 
      {{ object }} 
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

Comment: Thank you @pete!    
Unfortunately, that does not seem to have any output. 
`{{item.product.metafields.custom.object_upsell}}` --> Outputs an array as mentioned. 
`{{item.product.metafields.custom.object_upsell.values}}` --> Outputs nothing

Comment: I still think this is close check out this post https://community.shopify.com/c/technical-q-a/how-do-i-loop-through-a-text-metafield-list/td-p/1615541 try .value not .values this should target the array inside the metafield 
```
{% for item in cart.items %} {% if item.product.metafields.custom.object_upsell %} {% assign referencedObjects = item.product.metafields.custom.object_upsell.value %} {% for object in referencedObjects %} {{ object }} {% endfor %} {% endif %} {% endfor %}

Answer (score 0):

Add  "| first" after value try to fetch

```
{% assign list =  product.metafields.custom.product_varients.value | first   %}

{% for pro in  list.p_list.value  %}
  {% assign producturl = "/products/" | append:pro.handle %}
  {% assign index = forloop.index | minus: 1 %}
  <a href="{{ producturl }}">
    <span class="dot {% if producturl == product.url %}dot-selected{% endif %}" style="background-color: {{ list.p_color.value [index] }};"></span>
  </a>
{% endfor %}
```